# Pointer corrupted while returning from a function

Tags: c++, macos, pointers, memory, c++98

**TL;DR**: When I run my C++ program on a Mac under OS X Yosemite, a pointer gets corrupted while a function is returning. How do I stop it from happening? (and why?)

---

In [this sample program](https://gist.github.com/diazona/ba7f270d3e1763e6abf8), I have a data structure of type `category_map<T>` which is effectively just a

```
map<string, list<pair<string, T> > >
```

The `category_map` class has a couple of methods, including `get(string& name)` which pulls the `list` stored under the given `name` and returns the `T` from the first element of that list. In my case, `T` is a pointer type. The pointer that the code retrieves from the first `pair` in the `list` - that'd be `p` in the code listing below - is valid. A debugger session shows that the value of `p` on the last line of the function - the closing brace, before destructors run - is a valid memory location like, say, `0x100809c00`.

```
T& get(const string& name) const {
    cerr << "searching for " << name << endl;
    typename super::const_iterator map_iterator = super::find(name);
    // the real code doesn't assume it will be found
    list_type the_list = map_iterator->second;
    T& p = the_list.front().second;
    cerr << "found " << val_loc_string<T>(p) << endl;
    return p;
}
```

However, when I compile and run the code on a Mac (OS X Yosemite), but not on Linux, somewhere in the process of cleaning up from this function, something writes to the same location in memory, so that the returned pointer - stored in the variable `ip` in the next code listing below - is corrupted. For example, it might become `0x3000100809c00` or `0x5000100809c00`. The corrupted pointer is always the original pointer with one or a few extra bits set in the 2nd-most-significant byte of the 8-byte address.

```
int main(const int argc, const char** argv) {
    category_map<int*> imap;
    int a;
    imap.add("Q1", "m", &a);
    imap.add("Q1", "r", &a);
    imap.add("Q2", "m", &a);

    int* ip = imap.get("Q1");
    cerr << "return value: " << val_loc_string<int*>(ip) << endl;
    cout << *ip << endl;
}
```

Using GDB (installed through MacPorts) I've identified the specific instruction that writes the extra bits to the memory location.

```
   0x00007fff93188279:  cmp    $0x2,%eax
   0x00007fff9318827c:  jb     0x7fff9318828d
   0x00007fff9318827e:  shl    $0x4,%rax
=> 0x00007fff93188282:  mov    %r10w,-0x2(%rax,%rdx,1)
   0x00007fff93188288:  mov    %r10w,0x10(%rdx)
   0x00007fff9318828d:  test   %r10w,%r10w
   0x00007fff93188291:  jne    0x7fff93188299
```

([more context](https://gist.github.com/diazona/ba7f270d3e1763e6abf8#file-gdb_dump-s)) but this is not much help because it's not part of a C/C++ function, I'm not fluent enough in assembly to understand what it's doing on a large scale, and the [backtrace](https://gist.github.com/diazona/ba7f270d3e1763e6abf8#file-stack_trace-txt) is garbage so I can't put the code in context. (I've also captured the [values of the registers](https://gist.github.com/diazona/ba7f270d3e1763e6abf8#file-registers-txt) just prior to the instruction that corrupts the pointer, in case that helps for some reason.)

Since I instantiate `category_map<T>` only with pointer types, I *could* change the return type of `get` to `T` (instead of `T&`) and that does appear to solve (or at least work around) the problem. But it makes the data structure more generally useful if it can hold large objects and return them by reference, and I would think that should be possible. Plus, whatever error I've made in coding this, I would like to understand so I don't make it again. Can anyone point out what I did wrong, and the right way to fix it without changing the API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With

```
list_type the_list = map_iterator->second;
```

you make a copy of `map_iterator->second`. `the_list` is a function-local object. Then

```
T& p = the_list.front().second;
return p;
```

returns a reference to something that lives as long as this function-local object and is destroyed when the function is left. The reference dangles.

It looks to me as though you didn't intend to make a copy of the list, so

```
//          +------ const because get() is const-qualified
//          v   v-- reference
list_type const &the_list = map_iterator->second;

//  v-- const because the_list is const
T const& p = the_list.front().second;
```

should fix it, if you can make `get() const` return a `T const &`<sup>1</sup>. Otherwise you have the problem of attempting to return a reference to non-const member from a `const` member function; this would break const-correctness and is therefore forbidden (if it were allowed, you would be able to change constant objects through that reference).

<sup>1</sup> You could also make `get const()` return a value rather than a reference, but there doesn't seem to be a reason to force that copy.